# ReactJS AXIOS post doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, yii2, axios

I'm trying to submit a login form to an API, however, the API doesn't pass the post request test.

ReactJS Action:

```
/**
 * Sends login request to API
 */
export function login(email, password) {
    console.log('Credentials:', email, password)
    const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}login/login`, 
        {
            email,
            password
        })
        .then((response) => console.log(response))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

Login function from api:

```
    public function actionLogin($credentials = [])
    {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;

        if ($request->post()) { 
            // handle the user login
        } else {
            return Json::encode(['status' => false, 'data' => 'error_no_request']);
        }
    }
```

[image: Console logging the request]
Console logging the response - it's clear that it doesn't get through the request test.

Headers:

```
Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:42
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 20 Sep 2017 06:42:06 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=98
Server:Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.8
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.0.8

Request Headers
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:56
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host:127.0.0.1
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/login
```

[image]
Console logging the request.

Comment: if `the API doesn't receive the request` what is that a picture of? sure looks like an XMLHttpRequest with a 200 response status

Comment: Said that wrong. It receives the request, but it doesn't get to the login handling part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so since the POST method doesn't work, I tried it with the GET method. And for some reason, it works. The action now looks like:

```
export function login(email, password) {
    const request = axios({
        headers: { 
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'post',
        url: `${ROOT_URL}login/login`,
        params: {
            email,
            password
        }
    })
    .then((response) => response.data)
    .catch((error) => error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing body data as **null**.

Edit :

```
const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}login/login`, 
    {
        email,
        password
    })
    .then((response) => console.log(response))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

To :

```
const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}login/login`, 
    data:{
        email,
        password
    })
    .then((response) => console.log(response))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Body expects **data** keyword for the body data to which json object is attached for axios post request. 
Check the [documentation](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#axios-api)

Comment: Still doesn't work. Checked the documentation and works both ways

Comment: What does your network tabs shows the data that you are sending.?

Comment: @MoldovanAndrei Also set headers content-type as application/json instead of text/html

Comment: They're already set to application/json. Edited the question so you can see them.

Comment: Could you show what $request prints when API is hit?

Comment: I have added the logging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154858/discussion-between-shubham-jain-and-moldovan-andrei).